# React Js Conditional Render Another Component OnChange Event

Tags: reactjs

I've a component like below. I want to render specific data after clicking radio button.

```
class InstitutionType extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            service: '',
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <FormControl component="fieldset">
                    <FormLabel component="legend">Services</FormLabel>
                    <RadioGroup row aria-label="services" name="service" value={this.state.service} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                        <FormControlLabel value="school" control={<Radio />} label="School" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="college" control={<Radio />} label="College" />
                        <FormControlLabel value="university" control={<Radio />} label="University" />
                    </RadioGroup>
                </FormControl>
                
                // want to render specific data conditionally
                // <SchoolComponent /> or <CollegeComponent /> or <UniversityComponent />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default InstitutionType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an object to map radio values to their components:

```
const SERVICES = {
  school: <SchoolComponent />,
  college: <CollegeComponent />,
  university: <UniversityComponent />,
};

class InstitutionType extends React.Component {
  state = {
    ...
    serviceName: "",
  };

  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        {SERVICES[this.state.serviceName]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default InstitutionType;
```

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl component="fieldset">
                <FormLabel component="legend">Services</FormLabel>
                <RadioGroup row aria-label="services" name="service" value={this.state.service} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                    <FormControlLabel value="school" control={<Radio />} label="School" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="college" control={<Radio />} label="College" />
                    <FormControlLabel value="university" control={<Radio />} label="University" />
                </RadioGroup>
            </FormControl>
            
            // want to render specific data conditionally
            // <SchoolComponent /> or <CollegeComponent /> or 
       // <UniversityComponent />
        {
          service==="School"?<SchoolComponent />:service==="College"? 
          <CollegeComponent />: service==="University"?
          <UniversityComponent />:null
        }
        </div>
    )
}
```